# Convert plone database to csv or SQL

Tags: database, csv, plone

I am helping out an organization which are planning on changing their members system. Right now their system is developed in Plone and all their data is in a Data.fs file.

Their system is down for the moment and it would take some time and effort to get it up and running.

Is there a way to get the data out from the database into a standard format such as csv files or SQL? Or do they need to get the system up and running beforehand and export the files from "within" plone?

Thanks for your help and ideas!

Kind regards,
Samuel

Comment: Plone is not backed by a RDBMS -> *No* SQL in the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Data.fs` file is a Object Oriented Database file, and it is written by a framework called the [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/). The data within it represent python instances, layed out in a tree structure.

You *could* open this database from a python script, but in order for you to make sense of the contained structures, you'll need access to the original class definitions that make up the stored instances. Without those class definitions all you'll get is placeholder objects (Broken objects) that are of no use at all.

As such, it's probably easier to just get the Plone instance back up and running, as it'll be easier to export the exact data you want out if you have things like the catalog (basically a specialized database index) to build your export.

It could be that this site is down because of something trivial, something we can help you with here on Stack Overflow, or on the Plone users mailinglists or in the #plone IRC channel. If you do get it up and running and have some details on what you are trying to export, we certainly can help.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I guess I have to have the classes and it would probably be easier to get Plone going.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get the system up and running to export data.  Data in the data.fs file is stored as Python pickles and is not intelligible to "outside" systems.

Comment: Think Python classes as the database schema. Without the running and working schema the data is useless.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed out before, your best course would be to have Plone running back again.  After doing so, try [csvreplicata](http://plone.org/products/csvreplicata/) to export existing data to csv format.  And for user accounts, try [atreal.usersinout](http://plone.org/products/atreal.usersinout/).

If you need professional help, you can search for available providers from http://plone.org/support/providers

For free support, post specific problems here.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I managed to export Plone 4 site to sqlite using SQLExporter: http://plone.org/products/proteon.sqlexporter. But you need to get your Plone instance working first to use it.